# loop. 2outputs. only show one

Tags: php, sql, loops

I'm trying to get info from database with:

```php
$q = "SELECT * FROM PrEntries WHERE type ='0'";
$result = mysql_query($q);
$num_rows = mysql_numrows($result);
if(!$result || ($num_rows < 0)|| ($num_rows == 0)){
    echo "no username or reeor install";
}else{
    Echo "<h1>username</h1>";
    for($i=0; $i<$num_rows; $i++){
        $name = mysql_result($result,$i,"name");
        $entryid = mysql_result($result,$i,"entryid");
        Echo "<a href='index.php?userworld=$name'>$name</a><br />";
    }
    echo"</table>";
}}
```

that works. but in my database I have 2 places with the same name but different id. How do I make it so it only shows one of the names? And I have some places where the name is one time and some 4 times the same names, how to only show the name one time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select one row per `entryid`, use `group by`:

```
SELECT * FROM PrEntries WHERE type ='0' GROUP BY entryid
```